# Its possible to add a new class yii framework table's thead

Tags: yii

Hi i am using Yii framework. In this framework I'm using cgirdview table. on that table's thead i need to add new class it's possible.I just try to add image on thead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this CSS selector to target the `thead`:

```
.grid-view table thead {
```